# how do I test ng-add schematics

Tags: unit-testing, angular-cli, angular-schematics

I decided to add an ng-add schematic to my library, since there are additional setup steps when installing it past running npm/yarn install. This way, users will be able to run `ng add @myorg/mylib` and the schematics will run

I am having difficulty test running the schematic. [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/schematics-for-libraries#run-the-schematic) only mentions how to test `generate` schematics, not `add` ones. The problem is that the schematic is supposed to run when I install the library, however `ng add` command always seems to install the repository version, and not the local one *even if* I link my library with `yarn link`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got an answer before I submitted the question.

Do `yarn link mylibrary`, and then `ng add mylibrary`. `ng add` doesn't require the library not to be installed, it will try to install, but fail gracefully if the library is already installed with a warning

> Skipping installation: Package already installed

Your ng-add script probably contains `context.addTask(new NodePackageInstallTask());`. Since link already "installed" the library in your node_modules, this **will** fail. The solution is to comment this line out while you're developing, and reenable it before publishing.